# Is Apache Basic Auth w/ SSL "good enough" from a security standpoint?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, http-basic-authentication

Is using Apache Basic Auth with enforced SSL good enough to secure internal-only sites that must be publicly accessible? I know that there are more advanced Apache authentication protocols such as Digest, but I'm not sure if it's really necessary to implement something so complicated when a standard Basic Auth does the trick.

Comment: This previous posting has a good explanation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910207/is-apache-digest-authentication-more-secure-or-than-basic-or-not

Comment: Thanks man! I guess I'm sticking with Basic Auth then, since I have it secured with SSL. No point in fixing it if it's not broken. ᕕ(ᐛ)ᕗ